# How to iterate and encode list text instead of list?

Tags: python, csv, xpath, encoding, web-scraping

I have been trying to encode the list `price['value']`, getting the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`.  After realising the problem, I've tried a number of different ways to encode the text before it's added to the list, but none have worked.
How do I use `.encode('utf-8')` correctly in this situation in order to get non-unicode data in the results for `price['value']`, by encoding the text and not the list?

```
import mechanize
from lxml import html
import csv
import io
from time import sleep

def save_products (products, writer):

    for product in products:

        writer.writerow([ product["title"][0].encode('utf-8') ])
        for price in product['prices']:
            writer.writerow([ price["value"] ])

f_out = open('pcdResult.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

links = ["http://purechemsdirect.com/ourprices.html/" ]

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]


for link in links:

    print(link)
    r = br.open(link)

    content = r.read()

    products = []        
    tree = html.fromstring(content)        
    product_nodes = tree.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12"]')

    for product_node in product_nodes:

        product = {}
        try:
            product['title'] = product_node.xpath('.//p/strong/text()')

        except:
            product['title'] = ""

        price_nodes = product_node.xpath('.//ul')

        product['prices'] = []
        for price_node in price_nodes:

            price = {}
            try:
                price['value'] = price_node.xpath('.//li/text()')

            except:
                price['value'] = ""

            product['prices'].append(price)
        products.append(product)
    save_products(products, writer)

f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try a list comprehension since `price['value']` is a list. I'm assuming that the values inside `price['value']` are strings, not other lists. If there are more lists inside, then this answer will not work.

```
def save_products (products, writer):

for product in products:

    writer.writerow([ product["title"][0].encode('utf-8') ])
    for price in product['prices']:
        writer.writerow([x.encode('utf-8') for x in price['value']])
...
```

Comment: @qwertyuio9 Yes you're right it's strings and not other lists stored here.  Where in the code would I place this?

Comment: @McLeodx i edited my answer, let me know if this doesn't work